# IIS7 and IE6 ssl issues

Tags: iis-7, internet-explorer-6

I have a newly deployed mvc app on a win2008 server box.

I am trying to troubleshoot some very strange ie6 behaviour when over https.  if a ie6 user connects to the webserver over https a simple post back or ajax call takes around 1 minute to complete, no errors are raised on the browser, it just sits there ticking away for about a minute, then completes as expected (both server and client as expected).  the same post back or ajax call over http works in  < 2 seconds.

There are no errors or events raised on the server, so i am flying blind here.

has anyone experienced this behaviour before, any ideas? with no errors or events to work with im not sure where to start.  any other browser over https works fine, just ie6.

cheers
andrew

Answer (score 1):

a quick follow up on this one.  on further investigation the issue was only occurring on windows 2000 ie6 machines, xp and ie6 was ok.  I guess from these results there must be something in the encryption/decryption framework on windows 2000 conflicting with the iis7 server.

I have managed to convince the windows 2000 ie6 users that its time to upgrade!

This brings up another question, when, if at all, do you think its acceptable to block certain versions of software from your web apps?

andrew

Comment: It is perfectly normal to block some old versions, as you cannot afford so much to support something should be dead (Windows 2000 is already dead as Microsoft announces its end of support).